# Conservation of information

Tags: information, volume, holographic-principle

Given: The holographic principle as proposed by Susskind that states that the maximum amount of information stored in a 3D volume can be dictated by its surface area.

Would not: The simple square-cubed law of geometry indicate that the number of Planck scale volume elements needed to discretize the volume would exceed the number of Planck size area elements on the surface. Therefore, information on the surface would need to be resolved at sub-Planck scale.

In other words my question is how do you resolve the holographic principle and the uncertainty principle.

Comment: Yeah I see what you mean. I guess there’s some other limit being hit when it comes to information. I wonder if it has to do with the process of retrieving that info. If there is a 2h wide “bit” deep inside our cube, can we really read that? I guess we’d start at the outer layer of bits and read those and somehow get rid of them. Then the next layer. Meanwhile there are quantum realities and uncertainty principle. Maybe the holographic principle even accounts for our interacting in an ideal way but still hitting some hard limit with the math of that retrieval process. Interesting